# Shipping a data package on Mac

Tags: macos, installation, bundle

My product consists of an application itself plus an optional clipart collection. The clipart collection is a separate download which the user then "installs" on his PC so that the main application can find it.

I am currently porting the application from Windows to Mac, and while shipping the application is clear to me (via .app file), I am wondering how to ship the clipart collection on the Mac. What is the most common way to ship such additional data packages?

Would it be acceptable to ask the user to copy the clipart collection into his "Pictures" folder, or would another folder be more suitable? And can I use/create some kind of package similar to app bundles so that a) the user has to deal with one file only and b) my application can access the cliparts via the normal file system (non-zipped)?

Thanks,
Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sandboxed Mac app, which is the only app acceptable to Apple these days if you want your app on the app store, you cannot access folders outside of the apps container folder without explicit user interaction.

This makes it simple for you:

1. User selects "download clipart" menu option/whatever
2. You display a save dialog, asking where they want to save the clipart.
3. You deal with bookmarks, etc., allowing you to access the user's selected folder.
4. You download and save the clipart into that folder.

Job done: user decides.

If you later want access to the clipart you can save the bookmark, to the apps container folders, and other places, allowing your app access to it after it's been restarted.

See the [Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html) for details of steps 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, Mac App Store is a good point. Downloading the clipart from within the application might be a bit annoying for the user since the clipart collection file is *huge*, although it is indeed flexible that way. So the other option would be to ship the clipart as part of the app bundle, right? Any more options?

Answer (score 0):

The usual place to put this kind of data is into /Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/APPNAME/.  This would be appropriate if you are distributing outside of the Mac App Store.  Via the Mac App Store, then the data would go in similar relative location within the app sandbox.

Comment: That is what I do with application settings and such. In case of the clipart collection the user however needs to download and place the file manually (i.e. "install" it). Isn't the "Application Support" folder an hidden or at least not commonly accessed folder from a user perspective?